# Randomly generate prime number

Tags: c++

I'm trying to randomly generate a prime number but it doesn't seem to be working and instead just throws out a normal number.

I've tried playing around with the isPrime function, and changing where i generate the number

```cpp
bool isPrime(int n) {
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < n / 2; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (flag == 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
void generatePublicKey() {

    int p = 0;
    int q = 0;

    while (!isPrime(p)) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        p = rand();
    }

    std::cout << p;

}
```

Comment: Move the `if (flag == 0` bit to outside the `for` loop. Also `i <= n / i` is a better stopping condition, and repeated use of `srand` ruins the generator.

Comment: Please read more about [`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) and what it does. Think about what happens if you pass the same value over and over again to `srand` in the same loop where you call `rand` loop.

Comment: Aside: Since the majority of values are not primes, this is going to be inefficient. It's better to e.g. generate a random number, n, and then use a sieve to calculate the n'th prime.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Or, given that the number of primes below a number `x` is, to a remarkable approximation, `x/log x`, build a table of primes and use your random number to read a value from that table/

Comment: And one more thing, the probability of `x` being prime is about `1/log x`. So yes, inefficient indeed, although not as bad as you might think.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that's clearly not true for large numbers (for example you can generate a random 1024 bit prime with the sample and reject method, but you can't sieve that much), OTOH OP isn't dealing with large numbers and uses a slow primality test

Comment: @harold: Fair enough, I'll go buy some more memory right away ;)

Comment: Your sample code does not compile without warnings (`control reaches end of non-void function`). It's always a good idea to address compiler warnings before seeking outside aid in resolving bugs.

Comment: Consider: Seek out an example of "Sieve of Eratosthenes".  Use that algorithm to create some number of primes.  Then decide how to choose a random prime.  For instance, you might create a vector of the primes identified, shuffle the vector, then choose the first element of the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stopping condition doesn't work when `n` is 4. At a minimum it needs to be changed to `<=`.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i)
```

Better yet, I think the limit you're looking for is not ½n but √n. We should loop as long as `i <= sqrt(n)`, or equivalently:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; ++i)
```

---

The `flag` check should be outside the loop. When it's inside the loop it triggers the very first iteration which prevents the loop from completing.

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Any time you write `if (condition) return true; else return false;` it can be simplified to the shorter yet equivalent `return condition;`.

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag == 0;
}
```

You can even get rid of the flag if you just return `false` as soon as you find a divisor.

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
while (!isPrime(p)) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    p = rand();
}
```

You only want to seed the random number generator once. Re-seeding the PRNG every iteration is going to get you the same number over and over. Move the `srand()` call out of the loop.

It's also smart to change it to a do-while loop. You want to make sure you generate a random number before you call `isPrime`.

```
srand(time(NULL));
do {
    p = rand();
} while (!isPrime(p));
```

**Note:** It would be even better still to move the `srand()` call out of `generatePublicKey()` entirely. It should ideally be called once at the beginning of `main()`.

Comment: Consecutive calls to function will result in same number, either srand should be called somewhere earlier in the program or function should take a seed argument, but not like this.

Comment: @unlut: That depends on the use case. There are stronger generators in the new C++ standards, but good old `rand()` really isn't that bad.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Disregarding the fact that the use of the words "public key" suggests  `rand()` output is way too small (and not cryptographically secure) anyway, that isn't true. The overwhelming majority of implementations are really, really, really bad since they're simple LCGs implemented without much care. If you're lucky, you have MT as generator (though, for example, not on my system) which isn't so pathetic, but also not very well-suited for PK.